# I can't add Minecraft mulitplayer servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently bought the game and added lots of multiplayer severs that I love. One day I log in and they are all gone; I go onto direct connect and put in the correct IP and it says:

```
Outdated server, Still on {0}
```

How do I get my servers back?

Answer (score 2):

This means your client is updated and the servers you like playing on aren't (which is most likely the case because servers need to wait for plugins to be updated).

But with the Minecraft launcher you can choose to play on earlier versions of the game by editing the launcher settings with the Minecraft launcher "minecraft.exe" or other OS's equivalent. Go back to a previous version of Minecraft that you could play on the servers without error.

Answer (score 0):

Are those YOUR server or a server you like?

Either: the server must be updated. He is out of date or other: your version of mincraft is newer then the Server version and the Server owner must update the Version of his server or you must run Minecraft on the exact same version as the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're Minecraft version is more advanced (i.e. You: 1.8.0 Them: 1.7.10)
If you see a similar message reading

> outdated client

Then, they have a more advanced version.